# Android Music Widget To Be Used As LockScreen Widget

Tags: android, widget, android-4.4-kitkat, lockscreen

I am trying desperately to show my music widget on the lockscreen as well as on the desktop.
But no success :(

I have looked all over SO and google, tutorials and official android docs and havnt found why my widget is not diplayed (At All) at the lockscreen..

It's kinda simple widget with a very simple design so I dont see a reason why it is not shown.

I am trying to get this working on my One Plus One with KitKat Os.

Here is the code (hope it will help other users to create their widget as well):

**Java Code:**

```
public class MusicManager extends AppWidgetProvider {
boolean isLockScreen = false;
RemoteViews remoteViews;
Bundle options;

@Override
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

       Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Is Playing - " + Main.isPlaying);

    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            MusicManager.class);

    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
         options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(widgetId);
         menageResorces(context);

        // Play Intent
        initPlayIntent(context, allWidgetIds, remoteViews, appWidgetManager, widgetId);        

        // Next Intent
        initNextIntent(context, allWidgetIds, remoteViews, appWidgetManager, widgetId);

        // Prev Intent
        initPrevIntent(context, allWidgetIds, remoteViews, appWidgetManager, widgetId);

        // Main Intent
        initMainIntent(context, allWidgetIds, remoteViews, appWidgetManager, widgetId);

        //Shuffle
        initShuffleIntent(context, appWidgetIds, remoteViews, appWidgetManager, widgetId);

        //Repeat
        initRepeatIntent(context, appWidgetIds, remoteViews, appWidgetManager, widgetId);

        //Bypass
        initBypassIntent(context, appWidgetIds, remoteViews, appWidgetManager, widgetId);
      }
 }

 private void initPlayIntent(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews remoteViews,
         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId){
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(context, MusicManager.class);
        playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
        playIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);              
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay, pendingPlayIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
 }

 private void initNextIntent(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews remoteViews,
         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId){
        Intent fastForwardIntent = new Intent(context, MusicManager.class);
        fastForwardIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
        fastForwardIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingNextIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, fastForwardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNext, pendingNextIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
 }

 private void initPrevIntent(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews remoteViews,
         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId){
        Intent fastBackwardIntent = new Intent(context, MusicManager.class);
        fastBackwardIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
        fastBackwardIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingPrevIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, fastBackwardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPrevious, pendingPrevIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
 }

 private void initShuffleIntent(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews remoteViews,
         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId){
        Intent shuffleIntent = new Intent(context, MusicManager.class);
        shuffleIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.SHUFFLE);
        shuffleIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingShuffleIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, shuffleIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnShuffle, pendingShuffleIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
 }

 private void initRepeatIntent(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews remoteViews,
         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId){
        Intent repeatIntent = new Intent(context, MusicManager.class);
        repeatIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.REPEAT);
        repeatIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingRepeatIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, repeatIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnRepeat, pendingRepeatIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
 }

 private void initBypassIntent(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews remoteViews,
         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId){
        Intent bypassIntent = new Intent(context, MusicManager.class);
        bypassIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.BYPASS);
        bypassIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingBypassIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, bypassIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bypass, pendingBypassIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
 }

 private void initMainIntent(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews remoteViews,
         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId){
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MusicManager.class);
        mainIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        mainIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingMainIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.albumCover, pendingMainIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
 }

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
  final String action = intent.getAction();
  if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
       Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget DELETED");

   //The widget is being deleted off the desktop
   final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
     AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
     AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
   if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
       this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
   }
  } else {
      //Manage Play
      if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
          Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Play");
          //If Main is running
          if(isRunning(context)){
              Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Activity Running");
              Main.btnPlay.performClick();

          }
          //If Main is NOT running
          else{
              startMainActivity(context);                 
          }
      //Manage Next
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
           Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Next");
          //If Main is running
          if(isRunning(context)){
              Main.btnNext.performClick();
          }
          //If Main is NOT running
          else{
              startMainActivity(context);
          }
      //Manage Previous
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
           Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Previous");
          //If Main is running
          if(isRunning(context)){
              Main.btnPrevious.performClick();
          }
          //If Main is NOT running
          else{
              startMainActivity(context);
          }
      //Manage Main
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION)) {
           Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Main");
          if(!isRunning(context)){
              startMainActivity(context);
          }
          else{
              moveToFront(context) ; 
          }
      //Manage Shuffle
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.SHUFFLE)) {
           Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Shuffle");
          if(isRunning(context)){
              Main.btnShuffle.performClick();
          }
          else{

          }
      //Manage Repeat
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.REPEAT)) {
           Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Repeat");
          if(isRunning(context)){
              Main.btnRepeat.performClick();
          }
          else{

          }
      //Manage Bypass
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.BYPASS)) {
           Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Bypass");
          if(isRunning(context)){
              Main.bypass.performClick();
          }
          else{

          }
      }        
   super.onReceive(context, intent);
  }
 }

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void menageResorces(Context ctx){
         //Check if in lock screen or desktop
//       if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
//             try {
//                 int category = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_HOST_CATEGORY, -1);
//                 isLockScreen = category == AppWidgetProviderInfo.WIDGET_CATEGORY_KEYGUARD;
//                 Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Can Be In Lock Screen");
//          } catch (NullPointerException e) {
//              isLockScreen = false;
//          } 
//      }
//      else{
//          isLockScreen = false;
//      }
//      if(isLockScreen == true){
//             Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Is In Lock Screen");
//          remoteViews = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(),
//                  R.layout.lock_widget_layout);
//      }else{
        Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Widget Is NOT In Lock Screen");
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
//      }


    //Set album cover
    try {
        Bitmap icon;
        try {
            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(Main.songBeingPlayedPath);
            byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            icon = scaleDownBitmap(icon, 100, ctx);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                     R.drawable.list_image);
            icon = scaleDownBitmap(icon, 100, ctx);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                     R.drawable.list_image);
            icon = scaleDownBitmap(icon, 100, ctx);
        }

        try {           
            remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.albumCover, icon);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            try {
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                         R.drawable.list_image);
                icon = scaleDownBitmap(icon, 100, ctx);
                remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.albumCover, icon);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }       

    //Set play button image
    try {   
        //Set Song Label
        if(Main.songBeingPlayedTitle != null && Main.songBeingPlayedTitle.length() > 0){
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.songName, Main.songBeingPlayedTitle);

            try {
                if(Main.cameFromPlayerButtonWithShuffle == true)
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.album_name, Main.songListShuffle.get(Main.currentSongIndex).getAlbum());
                else
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.album_name, Main.songListAdapter.getItem(Main.currentSongIndex).getAlbum());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }
        }
        //Set Un Active
        else{
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.songName, ctx.getString(R.string.player_not_active));
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.album_name,"");
        }
        if(Main.isPlaying == true){
            Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Set Pause Button");
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnPlay, R.drawable.btn_pause);           
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Set Play Button");
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnPlay, R.drawable.btn_play);            
        }
        if(Main.isRepeat == true){
            Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Set Repeat On");
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnRepeat, R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);            
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Set Repeat Off");
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnRepeat, R.drawable.btn_repeat);            
        }
        if(Main.isShuffle == true){
            Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Set Shuffle On");
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnShuffle, R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);          
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Set Shuffle Off");
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnShuffle, R.drawable.btn_shuffle);          
        }
        if(Main.bypassed == true){
            Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Set Bypass On");
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.bypass, ctx.getString(R.string.bypass_440));           
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Widget Reciever", "Set Bypass Off");
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.bypass, ctx.getString(R.string.bypass_432));           
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }

 } 

 private void startMainActivity(Context ctx){
   Intent mainIntentStart = new Intent (ctx, Main.class);
   mainIntentStart.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   ctx.startActivity (mainIntentStart);
 }

 //Is Activity Running
 public boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
        if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) 
            return true;                                  
    }

    return false;
 }  

 //Move Activity To Front
protected void moveToFront(Context context) {
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
    {
           // bring to front                
           if (recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().indexOf("com.appums.music_pitcher") > -1) {                     
              activityManager.moveTaskToFront(recentTasks.get(i).id, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);

           }
    }
}

public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {

     final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        

     int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
     int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

     photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

     return photo;
 }
```

**Widget Provider Xml:**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
android:minWidth="216dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000" >
```

**Widget Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/purple" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/song_name_ll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/albumCover"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/list_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/songDetails_ll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/player_not_active"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/back_main"
            android:textSize="@dimen/indicator_text_small" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btns"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/alert_button_height"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/song_name_ll"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRepeat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/alert_button_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/nav_drawer_header_divider_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="@dimen/row_marging"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_repeat" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/alert_button_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/nav_drawer_header_divider_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_previous" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/alert_button_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/nav_drawer_header_divider_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_play" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/alert_button_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/nav_drawer_header_divider_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_next" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnShuffle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/alert_button_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/nav_drawer_header_divider_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="@dimen/row_marging"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_shuffle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bypass"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bypass_432"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/indicator_text_small" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**As I mentioned, The code and widget itself works perfectly!
It just does not show on lockscreen at all.**

Comment: Did you find out the answer to this? I'm trying to figure out if I need a widget for it or not. But even if I do, it won't be automatic? I'm confused. :(